# Apache Drill: Limit CPU/Memory when running in container

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, apache-drill

I am running Apache Drill and Zookeeper on a Kubernetes cluster. When Drill does not have enough CPU/Memory the entire VM is freezing. Does anyone know the best way to configure this to limit the CPU and Memory utilization?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit Drill memory usage with the following env variables: `DRILLBIT_MAX_PROC_MEM`, `DRILL_HEAP`, `DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY`.

For details please refer to https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-drill-memory/

Comment: Thanks for the guidelines in regard with memory.  Do you have any suggestions for CPU?

Comment: If you have allocated a low CPU for the pod, you might be also interested in decreasing the `planner.width.max_per_node` option value. By default, Drill will have a value of 70% of the total number of cores on a pod.

Comment: In case the pod contains only the drill engine, does make sense to play with planner.width.max_per_node? Or is not necessary anymore since only drill is in the pod.

Comment: In this case, there is no need to change it.